# How to access previous row values from partitioned data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with X and Y column as shown below.

I need to add another column Z which is the mean of the current and previous 2 rows of column Y. Also when X value changes, mean should be recalculated as shown. I know I can use the shift function for the entire dataframe to calculate the mean, but how do I recalculate the mean as and when X value changes.

```
X   Y   Z
a   1   1
a   2   1.5
a   3   2
a   4   3
b   10  10
b   20  15
b   30  20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `groupby` with `rolling`:

```
df['Z'] = df.groupby('X')['Y'].rolling(3,min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   X   Y     Z
0  a   1   1.0
1  a   2   1.5
2  a   3   2.0
3  a   4   3.0
4  b  10  10.0
5  b  20  15.0
6  b  30  20.0
```

Comment: You saved my my day once again! Thanks Scott!!

Comment: @piRSquared and pjs.  Thank you.

Comment: @piRSquared. I upvoted it now. It was not allowing me earlier as I didn't have the needed reputations to vote!

Comment: Thanks.   Much appreciated.